# Keep original page opening without upgrading to local version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Every morning I open this site to see the games of the day, but I like to see it in the international version (`https://int.`) because I don't like the brazilian version (`https://br.`).

But whenever I open it through `WebDriver` as it doesn't know that I prefer it that way (in my normal browser the preference is already saved and I don't need to adjust it), he open it in the `int` version but it automatically converts to the `br` version.

To work around this problem the only way I could find was to ask the `WebDriver` to open the same page twice (that way from there it registers which version I want to use):

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from os import path

def web_driver():
    service = Service(log_path=path.devnull)
    options = Options()
    options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", my_user_agent)
    options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,service=service)
    return driver

driver = web_driver()
driver.get("https://int.soccerway.com/")
driver.get("https://int.soccerway.com/")
```

When the page takes too long to load, this causes a problem because I never know when it has already been updated or when it will be updated, making me generate movements or clicks on the page that, after activating the second driver.get, returns to the top of the page.

How can I proceed to open the page and it will always remain in the version that I initially want?

I tried to find in the `cookies` which I should use to pass, but I couldn't understand which to use and whether to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is by opening the URL and changing the country to Internationl. See the below code:

```
# Open the below URL
driver.get('https://int.soccerway.com/')
# wait applied
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
# below line clicks the AGREE button on the pop-up
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='AGREE']").click()
# below line clicks country selection button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='site-header']/div/div/span[1]/span").click()
# below line clicks English International
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://int.soccerway.com']").click()
# below line clicks the AGREE button on the pop-up
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='AGREE']").click()
```

**UPDATE:** Below code uses the existing default browser profile.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(
    "user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="<give path here>\\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=options)

driver.maximize_window()

# Open the below URL
driver.get('https://int.soccerway.com/')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your attention, but I already used it like this, selecting the int option among the others that appear on the page, but this generates the same problem in the way I currently use it and it is much slower. My question in fact is whether there is a way to open it directly as I do in my browser that has preferences and cookies already saved (because with webdrive it always opens without any records).

Comment: Try the updated answer. See if this solution resolves your issue. This is using the existing browser profile. Make sure you manually open the website once and select International and close the browser, so that your browsing history is stored in the profile.

Comment: I only changed one thing (which would be even interesting if you added it to your answer), instead of using an existing profile, I created a new one just for this use.